# How to write a decimal for loop in bash

Tags: bash

How can I write a decimal for loop in bash

I get an error like

```
((: upgradver=1.00: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00")
```

I am trying something like

```
upgradever=1.00
newver=1.06
for (($ver=$upgradever; $ver<$newver; $ver+=0.01))
do
    echo "Upgrade to $ver"
done
```

Comment: Bash can not perform floating point math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two approaches:

#### Using `bc`

The shell does not do floats but the standard utility `bc` does.  This will do your loop:

```
upgradever=1.00
newver=1.06

ver=$upgradever
while [ 1 = "$(echo "$ver < $newver" | bc -l)" ]
do
    echo "Upgrade to $ver"
    ver=$(echo "$ver + 0.01" | bc -l)
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ bash script.sh
Upgrade to 1.00
Upgrade to 1.01
Upgrade to 1.02
Upgrade to 1.03
Upgrade to 1.04
Upgrade to 1.05
```

#### Pure bash solution via switching to hundredths

```
upgradever=100
newver=106
for ((ver=$upgradever; $ver<$newver; ver+=1))
do
    printf -v version '%s.%02i' "$((ver/100))" "$((ver%100))"
    echo "Upgrade to $version"
done
```

Output:

```
$ bash  sscript.sh
Upgrade to 1.00
Upgrade to 1.01
Upgrade to 1.02
Upgrade to 1.03
Upgrade to 1.04
Upgrade to 1.05
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Just for the record. If you can utilize the **pure bash** approach, it is much more efficient (over 105 iterations `100-206` -- `real 0m0.026s; user 0m0.018s; sys 0m0.006s`) compared to `bc` (`1.00-2.06` -- `real 0m1.134s; user 0m0.226s; sys 0m0.572s`)

Answer (score 2):

In short, you "can't," in the sense that the Bourne shell doesn't "do" floating-point math.

You can, however, use another scriptable tool, like Perl, to do it for you:

```
 $ver = $(perl -e "print $ver + .01")
```

see also `bc`, `awk`, or other tools.

Comment: Thanks @BRPocock - I want to accept your answer too - but I can only pick one and you were a few milliseconds behind John1024  - will give you +1 one though

Comment: No worries, their answer was decidedly more complete :-) well earned.

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't support floating point numbers, but there is a program BC (Best Calculator) that supports decimal arithmetic.

```
upgradever="1.00"
newver="1.06"

for (( i=$(bc<<<"($upgradever*100)/1"); $i<$(bc<<<"$newver/0.01"); i++ )); do
      echo $(bc<<<"0.01 * $i")
done
```

Comment: you are late for 1 hour:)

Comment: I think `bc` means _basic calculator_ and not _best calculator_.