# Increment subversion by one but keep leading zeroes

Tags: bash, perl

Please note that I couldn't find an answer to this exact question. There are answers on how to increment a version, but that is not the problem. The question is how to increment it and keep the leading zeros :)

So my problem is I'm trying to make a script that icrements my subversion by one, but keeping the leading zero.

My version number will always have at least 2 places in minor version field, but may have more. If the minor version is below 10 it will have a leading zero.

For example if my current version is "1.15" then it becomes "1.16". And if its "1.00" then it becomes "1.01".

I have the first part covered, but keeping the leading zeros is problematic.

```
# This return 1.16 as expected
echo '1.15' | perl -i -pe "s/\d*\.\K.+/$&+1/e"

# This return 1.100 as expected
echo '1.99' | perl -i -pe "s/\d*\.\K.+/$&+1/e"

# This return 1.1, but expected is 1.01
echo '1.00' | perl -i -pe "s/\d*\.\K.+/$&+1/e"
```

So as you can see the last case is problematic. Any tips to how to work around this are very welcome :)

Comment: Your previous question was duplicated couple of days back and it seems you deleted and posted the exact same one again now. Did you try searching similar questions to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I thought I saw this yesterday too. Anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073698/how-to-write-a-decimal-for-loop-in-bash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a decimal for loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073698/how-to-write-a-decimal-for-loop-in-bash)

Comment: Yes, the question was closed as duplicate, but the proposed answers did not answer the same question and stackoverflow suggested asking the question again in this case. I'm afraid those suggested answers also don't provide any ideas on how to solve this in my perl substitution.

Comment: The link I provided gives a perl option.

Comment: And this is why i posted a new question. The last question was closed exactly the same way. Just a bunch of random suggested anwsers which do not address the asked question.

Answer (score 1):

You need autoincrement `++`, not `+`:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' '1.15' '1.99' '1.00' | perl -pe 's/\d+\.\K(\d+)/$x=$1;++$x/e'
1.16
1.100
1.01
```

Assigning `$1` to a temporary variable is done because `$1` is read only.